# vermagic of the module different from the kernel version that it was compiled for

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Hello everyone I am getting a strange string after my kernel version, in my module binary.

uname -r
5.11.0-rc7-eudyptula-FireBytZ-dirty

Source of the module with Makefile: https://github.com/Rajssss/BBG_linux_4.14_custom_device_drivers/tree/master/pseudo_char_driver

```
modinfo main.ko
.......
vermagic: 5.11.0-rc7-eudyptula-FireBytZ-00001-g7edd5e14de63 SMP mod_unload
```

But it should be: `vermagic: 5.11.0-rc7-eudyptula-FireBytZ-dirty SMP mod_unload`

That's why insmod gives Invalid format error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can commit your changes (locally) and `dirty` part will gone.

Comment: Commit where? I am using linux-headers, not a full linux tree.
Actually, I want "dirty" instead of "00001-g7edd5e14de63" at the end.

Comment: It's impossible to build kernel from kernel headers. **dirty** means that you have a Git repository (or sources that sounds like a Git repository) on which there are **uncommitted** changes. You may look into the script which adds that.

Comment: I am not building the kernel, I am building the module.

Comment: I guess whoever built and installed the kernel must have committed the changes to the git repo afterwards, causing later external module builds to pick up the updated local version information that is different to the previously built kernel.

Comment: As Ian answered you may not achieve the result without recompiling kernel with all changes saved into repository (locally).